# Recovering/repairing partition map following Linux installation/removal

Tags: hard-drive, mac, partitioning, partition-recovery, boot-partition

Through a variety of Linux installations (and reinstallations) this evening, I seem to have borked the drive in my MacBook Pro. Gparted at some stage reported drive errors and tried to "fix" them, unsuccessfully, possibly causing the issue I'm now seeing.

The partition still seems to be there, and while things *look* okay from the outside, the Mac won't boot, and holding Option at startup gives me no drives aside from Internet Recovery.

I have screenshots from Internet Recovery and Disk Utility, and can create a bootable thumb drive if necessary.

Can anyone tell what's wrong with my partition map, and what (if anything) I can do to get things shaped up?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**edit: Output from `gdisk`:**

[image]

Comment: You probably want to delete this and ask over on ["Ask Different" aka apple.stackexchange.com](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the `disk0s2` partition has a wrong/bogus partition type GUID.

If that was a modern CoreStorage partition, its GUID should be:
`53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`

If that was an older HFS+ partition, its GUID should be:
`48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`

I don't have any advice for how to fix the GUID type back to what it should be, other than, "Be very careful, make sure you have good backups, and TEST YOUR BACKUPS before proceeding."

Comment: There is a great Mac disk recovery tool out there a co-worker once told me about but I can't think of the name!!

Comment: @JimLohse Alsoft DiskWarrior has had a great reputation for a long time, but I haven't needed it in years.

Comment: That's what I was trying to think of!!! One of the smartest level2+ tech support people I ever knew at Apple liked that one. I think he's at an Apple store in Omaha now, reason enough to move to Omaha :) Thanks!

Comment: Even updating the UUID of the partition (and recreating the GPT table) leaves me without any "bootable" drives. With GPT/EFI, is there anything in particular that is used to determine whether a partition is bootable or not?

Comment: @CraigOtis Well, what did you change the GUID to? And was it properly readable/writable, just not bootable? Or was it still not even readable?

Comment: I changed the GUID to the HFS type (`4846...`). It still behaves as it does in the original screenshots, appearing as `disk0s2` in Disk Utility, and unmountable. (While "Mount" is enabled and clickable, clicking it does nothing.) I also tried mounting it with `mount -t hfs /dev/disk0s2 /Volumes/mystuff`, which fails with `mount_hfs: Invalid argument`. I've tried making the partition huge (to the end of the disk) and also a little bit smaller than it currently is. I'm really just trying to figure out _what_ would make it mountable/readable.

Comment: If you deleted and re-created the partition table, that was overkill, and may have created new problems. In particular, the new partitions ***MUST*** begin and end at ***EXACTLY*** the same points as the originals, or they won't work. If the start and end points are identical to the original, then the partition *contents* are damaged, not the partition table. Disk Utility *might* be able to correct filesystem damage, but that depends on the nature of the damage.